# How can I pessimistically lock multiple rows in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to pessimistically lock a subset of a table (Postgres) for conditional inserts and am having a heck of a time finding a syntax that works. Here's basically what I'm trying to do:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  if consumer.purchases.lock.sum(&:amount) < some_threshold
    consumer.purchases.create!(amount: amount)
  end
end
```

Unfortunately the above doesn't work. But it feels like it should. I just need to lock all the rows for a specific consumer without locking the whole table. And unfortunately, I'm dealing with real money, it's a ledger of sorts, so it's gotta be bulletproof.

`consumer.purchases.lock.to_sql` results in `SELECT "purchases".* FROM "purchases" WHERE "purchases"."consumer_id" = ? FOR UPDATE` as I would expect, but 
for some reason, chaining `.create!` causes the query builder to remove the `FOR UPDATE` lock.

Ok, so I've pulled it apart and tried various things that I think should work but **DON'T**:

```
# Process 1
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  consumer.purchases.tap{ |p| p.lock! }.create!(amount: amount)
  sleep 20
end

# Process 2
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  consumer.purchases.tap{ |p| p.lock! }.create!(amount: amount)
  # Should wait but doesn't
end
```

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  purchases = Consumer.find(3).purchases
  purchases.lock
  purchase = purchases.new(amount: amount)
  purchase.save!
  sleep 20
end

... Other process doesn't wait...
```

The only way I **CAN** get it working is if I lock the rows iteratively; this **DOES** work:

```
# DOES WORK!
# Process 1
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  purchases = Consumer.where(id: 3).first.purchases
  purchases.each(&:lock!)
  purchase = purchases.new(amount: amount)
  purchase.save!
  sleep 20
end

# Process 2
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  purchases = Consumer.where(id: 3).first.purchases
  purchases.each(&:lock!)
  purchase = purchases.new(amount: amount)
  purchase.save!
  # waits as it should
end
```

But I can't be asked to lock them iteratively, that's insane :)
So I got to thinking maybe it's a weird Postgres quirk? (I'm much more familiar with MySQL), so I did it by hand in Postgres and it works no problem:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM purchases WHERE consumer_id = 3 FOR UPDATE;
SELECT pg_sleep(30);
INSERT INTO purchases (name, amount) VALUES ('shouldBlock30Seconds', '1000');
END;

BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM purchases WHERE consumer_id = 3 FOR UPDATE;
INSERT INTO purchases (name, amount) VALUES ('shouldWait30Seconds', '1000');
END;

BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM purchases WHERE consumer_id = 24839992 FOR UPDATE;
INSERT INTO purchases (name, amount) VALUES ('shouldInsertImmediately', '1000');
END;
```

`shouldInsertImmediately` gets inserted right away, `shouldBlock30Seconds` gets inserted after 30s, and `shouldWait30Seconds` gets inserted immediately after.

I'm pulling my hair out :)
Has anyone run across this before or am I just very tired and missing something obvious?

(Rails 5.1.7, Ruby 2.4.1, Postgres 11.6)

Comment: There is a huge difference between `sum(:amount)` and `sum(&:amount)`. Remember that `&:method_name` is shorthand for passing a block. The former does a query and selects a count from the database. The later is Enumerable#sum and will loop through the records in ruby and call amount on each record and then sum that up which can be a performance problem.

Comment: Ha, I was wondering if someone would catch that :) It's actually on purpose because Postgres can't lock with aggregate functions, you'll get `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::FeatureNotSupported: ERROR:  FOR UPDATE is not allowed with aggregate functions`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`purchases.lock` does not lock anything, it only returns a new relation, that will lock records on fetch.

Try forcing the select: `purchases.lock.to_a`

Comment: Thank you for saving my sanity :)  I'm low on sleep and had tried `purchases.lock.all` thinking I had that covered. How embarrassing. Still not digging the api though. It really feels like the query builder should hang onto it so that you can chain it into CollectionProxys/Relations wherever you please.

Comment: Had a similar issue because I didn't update records from the locked relation. So this worked: `Item.transaction { Item.lock.where(id: ids); Item.where(id: ids).each(&:smth) }` It's a select for update, so I just did the update after lock.